# How to close port manually at server using putty or WinSCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, putty, winscp

In my java web application i am using certain ports like 1025,10..,10.. .after restarting tomcat in server .the port used by tomcat project are not closing ,it is still open

how to close the port manually using putty or WinSCP file editing
any solution for closing the port

Comment: identify the process using the port with netstat and kill the process

Comment: I don't know is it possible but it looks like resource leaking nevertheless

Comment: By what means have you ensured that you are actually restarting Tomcat? Maybe it's left hanging (a common occurrence).

Comment: using putty i am restarting tomcat7 service

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nirsoft's [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) utility to manually close TCP connections. That said, it is not necessarily the right thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Get to the tomcat directory and run ***shutdown.sh*** script and now you can re-use those ports. Hope this helps, if not comment the response.

If this doesn't solve.

1. Find the process id or pid using `netstat` command.
2. Verify that pid    using `lsof` if linux or pfiles for solaris
3. Kill using `kill`

hope this helps. In a server there will be multiple processes running some of which you might not know, those processes might use your ports(sharing). While using netstat watch for CLOSE_WAIT status (these are killer handing processes) you must get rid of them in a safe way

Comment: Thank you for the response.when i restart or start again server that port are in use .in my application tomcat uses 8080 and my service ports 1025,10.. etc.my service ports are not clossing .same problem remains

Comment: @NN may be some other process is using those ports, if its not a share resource. I mean if it is a test server then kill those process by using kill command. (check answer for details)

if this solves your problem rate up the answer / accept the answer so the question will be closed.